# How parse current time in an HH:MM format

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I need to convert a string that looks like current time (in hours:minutes):

For instance: 16:00, 17:34, 00:19 etc
I need to convert them to date objects, looking like:

`Thu Nov 25 2021 17:34:00 GMT+0300` (my local date and time zone, but current time replaced by the rendered value).

Using date-fns it throws an error:

```js
import parse from "date-fns/parse";
 
const now = new Date()

const a = parse("23:00", "HH:mm", new Date());
console.debug(a);
```

Error is:

```
Invalid Date
```

What is the reason?

Comment: you can do `let date = new Date(); date.setHours(hh); date.setMinutes(mm);`

Comment: @Photon ... `date.setSeconds(0); date.setMilliseconds(0);`

Answer (score 1):

It's because date-fn don't see the string "23:00" as a valid date data

to fix this date-fn implement a parse-iso which take a string and return a valid ISO date
https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/parseISO

```
var parseISO = require('date-fns/parseISO')

const a = parse(parseISO("23:00"), "HH:mm", new Date());
console.debug(a);
```

depending on date-fns version but normally parse as you did is working https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-forked-dxy95

```
parse("23:00", "HH:mm", new Date());
```

if you want a string that contain only the hour in format HH:mm you can do

```
import format from "date-fns/format";
const b = format(new Date(), 'HH:mm');
```

Comment: nope, the same 'invalid date' error. https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-forked-zrwht?file=/src/index.js

Comment: here you will found ttwo working sample https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-forked-dxy95

Comment: no issue with parse("23:00", "HH:mm", new Date());  it depend on date-fns version the need of parse Ido or not

Answer (score 0):

```js
let event = new Date();
event.setHours(23,59,59);
console.log(event);
```

or with a custom date

```
const event = new Date('Thu Nov 25 2021 17:34:00 GMT+0300');

setHours(hoursValue, minutesValue, secondsValue, msValue)
```

You can read more about these functions and others in the Mozilla documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities right now. there are probably many more. One would be to work with regular expressions and the other would be to use Js Date functions as in the example below:

```js
function get_HH_MM() {
  const t = new Date()
  _minutes = t.getMinutes();
  minutes = _minutes.toString().length == 1 ? '0'+_minutes : _minutes.toString();
  return (t.getHours() + ':' + minutes);
}

console.log(get_HH_MM());
```

**small note:** output will be a string.